# C# task schedule modify

Tags: c#, windows, scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling, taskscheduler

I'am trying to modify a scheduled task, manually created in Windows task scheduler, using C# application

[image]

using the following code:

```
rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(taskEdit.Name, 
            taskDefinition, 6, null, null, _TASK_LOGON_TYPE.TASK_LOGON_NONE, null);
```

My code works perfectly when I perform this operation in the principal task scheduler folder.
 But when I try to modify a task in a subfolder I got the error

> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

If try to use *username* and *password* instead of *null* as follow:

```
rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(taskEdit.Name, taskDefinition, 6, "username", "pwd", 
                           _TASK_LOGON_TYPE.TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN_OR_PASSWORD, null);
```

I got the error below:

```
(48,4):UserId:
```

Any ideas? Really Thanks!

Comment: Is `(48,4):UserId:` the full error message?

Comment: Sorry @Quantic, there are not other details in the error message; just the error code (-1072894421)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution, at least for develop time...I have to run Visual Studio as administrator. In this way I can modify tasks in whatever folder.

Comment: In production environment I set username and password (username as  DOMAIN\username) and the user must be an administrator.

Answer (score 1):

One solution for your issue is you can use Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper, download at https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/.

This is a very powerful wrapper that can work with Windows Task Scheduler and can handle the issue "Access is denied" also.

Comment: I'm using it now and getting this same error message back.